# Please help me to reinstall ubuntu without losing data!

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, reinstall

Not showing free-space while reinstalling Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

[image: Ubiquity partition manager]

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one partition then you have to copy all data from ubuntu live CD or Stick. If you have a separate Home or Partition then you can Install ubuntu normally. Just reinstall ubuntu to SDA1 partition. When installing select

something else

Selece SDA1 and click chage. Select partition to ext4, mount point to "/", check format

Swap as usual

If want to create home with another partition just mount to /home

Comment: This is all wrong, for a number of reasons. sda1 is the EFI partition. Checking *format* will wipe the /home. They're using LVM.